# How to apply an offset to Tumbling Window, in order to delay the starting of Windows<TimeWindow> in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

I'm calculating a simple mean on a dataset with values for May 2022, using different windows sizes. Using 1 hour windows there are no problems, while using 1 week and 1 month windows, records are not evaluated correctly.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72771300/flink-aggregatefunction-in-tumblingwindow-is-automatically-splitted-in-two-windo/72784720) the problem is due to the fact that *time is divided since the Unix epoch (01-01-1970) into equal-sized chunks (windows) of the specified duration, and then incoming events are assigned into those chunks (windows)*.

So this means that using 31 days windows, in Kafka Streams time is divided like that:

```
 01-01-1970 : 31-01-1970
 01-02-1970 : 03-02-1970
 ...
[14-04-2022 : 15-05-2022] <-- Our Window
 16-05-2022 : 15-06-2022
 ...
```

so not having the `01-05-2022 : 31-05-2022` window as desired.

In that [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72771300/flink-aggregatefunction-in-tumblingwindow-is-automatically-splitted-in-two-windo/72784720) (about Flink), the solution was to **apply an offset of 17 days** to the Tumbling Window, in order to shift the window start from `14-04` to `01-05`:

```
var monthResult = keyed
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(31),Time.days(17)))
        .aggregate(new AvgQ1(Config.MONTH))
        .name("Monthly Window Mean AggregateFunction");
```

But using Kafka Stream, i don't found an offset function, or something that let me to achieve the same result.

This is how i'm actually defining my window:

```
var grouped = keyed
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.Long(), EventSerde.Event()))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(10)))
    .reduce((o, v1) -> o);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `TimeWindow` implementation in Kafka Streams.

Cf https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.1.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/window/DailyTimeWindows.java

There is a ticket to add it natively to Kafka Streams, but demand was not super high and so it was never done. If you want to pick it up, it would be great!